# How can I set the color of the wave modifier?

Tags: animation, modifiers, color

I am trying to illustrate with a color (highlighter) how a wave travels across the surface or/and through an object from one point of its surface to an opposite point on the object. For example, for a blue colored cube I would like to show an expanding yellow circle which starts from a vertex in the middle of its right side, then expands (scales up) until it reaches the edges of that side, then it moves to left over the top-bottom-front-back sides (as a rectangle/plane) and then finally it is displayed scaling down on the surface of the left side until it disappears. Can such animation be done with the wave modifier? Can the color of the wave be changed (not the texture)? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: The color attributes of an object are only altered by their texture. I would simply add a gradient mapped to the height of your wave so that as the position of the wave travels it pokes up into the gradient (blend) texture. Otherwise you would have to do it with dynamic paint and an intersecting paint brush object.